# Gltf animation not playing/exporting properly

Tags: animation, scripting, error, gltf

In a project I'm working on, to create a visual in a gltf that the gameboy screen is moving, I ran a script that tells each and every panel to move back and let the next move forward, thus making it seem as if the screen is doing something. However, When I export all goes well except for the last two screens. the seem to be out of place way to the right until its their turn to show. I tried to delete the last two screens, But all it did was recreate the problem with the screens left. There is 17 screens in total And a BG screen that should not move. Any Idea how this could be fixed?
[image]
[image]
This is he script I used:

```
import bpy

# Number of frames to show each image
duration = 21

# X position of plane when it's in the front
x_front = 0.644278

# X position of the plane when it's in the back
x_back = -0.183634

# Fix inconsistent name for 1scr
if "1scr" in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects["1scr"].name = "1src"

# Remove 18src, it's a copy of 1src
if "18src" in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.data.objects["18src"])

last_n = 17
for n in range(1, last_n + 1):
    name = "%dsrc" % n
    ob = bpy.data.objects[name]
    action_name = ob.name + "Action"

    # Clear out existing animations
    ob.animation_data_clear()
    if action_name in bpy.data.actions:
        bpy.data.actions.remove(bpy.data.actions[action_name])

    action = bpy.data.actions.new(action_name)
    action.id_root = 'OBJECT'
    fc = action.fcurves.new(
        data_path="location",
        index=0,
        action_group="Location",
    )

    pts = []
    f = (n-1)*duration
    if n != 1: pts += [0, x_back]
    pts += [f, x_front]
    if n != last_n: pts += [f + duration, x_back]
    elif duration > 0: pts += [f + duration - 1, x_front]

    fc.keyframe_points.add(len(pts) // 2)
    fc.keyframe_points.foreach_set("co", pts)
    for pt in fc.keyframe_points: pt.interpolation = 'CONSTANT'

    # Push to NLA track
    ob.animation_data_create()
    track = ob.animation_data.nla_tracks.new(prev=None)
    track.name = "nouns"
    track.strips.new(action.name, 0, action)
    track.mute = True
    track.is_solo = False
```

Here is a link to the blender file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/ae4yob23aw2h0f0/NOUNS+GB+BLENDER.zip/file

Comment: lol I wrote that script specifically for your last file, it probably won't work on any other file.

Comment: Its seems to work fine until that last bit. I changed it up to specify where the planes should be exactly as this one has the planes in a new location.

Comment: Do you think you could help me out please? I realized the link was to a file that was not updated. I went ahead and updated the link to the correct one.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is it moves the panels on the X axis, which in this model is left-right. You need to move on the Y axis this time. You can change the `index=0,` to `index=1,` to make it do the Y axis, but I don't know if it will work. Like I said it was just an off-one script. (Also remember to pack images into your .blend before uploading.)